# How do I control the width of the last column?

Tags: css

When I add the width to the td it makes the th bigger.

If the last column has a lot of text but I don't want the width to show in the whole page, how do I control it?

I would still want to have the `th` be `nowrap` and the 'Replacement' and 'Additional test' will always be yes/no text.

I made a https://jsfiddle.net/6Lmt5vjc/

```
table.standardtable {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
table.standardtable th,
table.standardtable td {
    padding: 5px 9px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000;
    }
table.standardtable th{
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
table.standardtable th.section1{
    background-color: #04659D;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #044971;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use css selectors to find the last `<td>` and apply a max-width to it:

```
 table.standardtable tr td:last-child{ /* last-child returns the last instance of the td */
   max-width:150px;
   /* additional styles as required */
 }
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lmt5vjc/1/)

One thing to note on your fiddle, don't use `<td>` and `<th>` mixed. `<th>` is a table header, where as `<td>` is a regular cell. Although technically your markup works it is not good practice.

Valid table would be something like:

```
<table>
<tr>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you want to alter the markup, use `css classes` instead.